# Issues Converting DEM to a Lower Resolution in QGIS 3

Tags: dem

I am having issues converting a 1 m DEM to a 5 m DEM on QGIS. I am working in the NAD83 UTM 20 projection and whenever I convert my 1 m DEM to 5 m DEM the output is always less than 5 (often 4.9987 or something like that).

My thoughts were that this was a projection issue giving the odd numbers but I tried to reproject and the issue remains. I thought that since maybe all my DEMs were at this resolution it would be ok for my purposes, but I am having issues using the SAGA accumulated cost algorithm and I am thinking it's probably related to the DEM resolution.

Any guidance?

Comment: What options are you using to convert your 1m DEM to 5m DEMs?

Comment: I have been just clicking 'Export as' and changing the resolution then saving as a new file. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this issue. I just used the Warp Projection under the Projection tab in the Raster toolbar. I was able to adjust the resolution that way. This also solved the other issues I was having processing Accumulated Costs with the DEMs.